# Codeigniter-Limit 2 image per page in window.print()

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, sql-server-2008

Good day everyone. So I have this working code that shows image from a folder using the image names that is saved in my database. So basically, Folder(image_name) = Table(image_name).

Model (print_model)

```
public function get_names($acknowledgement_key) {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('TblPrintImage')
            ->where('acknowledgement_key', $acknowledgement_key)
            ->order_by('img_id', 'asc')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

View (print_view)

```
<?php foreach ($saved as $data) { ?>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12" >
   <br>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
     <tr style="text-align: center;font-family: Times New Roman;font-size: 16px;color: black; font-weight: bolder">
      <td><br></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>                                                                                
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">                                                                                        
         <img src="<?php echo base_url("./uploads/" . $data->img_name . ".jpg"); ?>" width="650" height="224" alt=""/>                                  
        </div>                                                          
       </div>                                                            
       <div class="row">                                                  
        <div class="col-xs-12" >                                                 
         <textarea class="form-control" style="overflow: hidden; resize: none; border: 0; background: transparent; font-size: 14px;" maxlength="500" rows="5" name="" id="" ><?php echo $data->findings ?>
         </textarea>                                                           
        </div>                                                           
       </div>                                                                            
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Controller (print_controller)

```
public function print($acknowledgement_key) {
$data ['saved'] = $this->print_model->get_names($acknowledgement_key);
$this->load->view('print_view', $data);
}
```

The PROBLEM is, because it was called as an array, it will also show in a group of an array like this in window.print();.[image]

What I want is to limit in to 2 (two) image per page in window.print(); like this.[image]
I hope that I explained this will because i've been stuck in solving this since yesterday. Thanks guys.

Comment: Why don't you just limit the results?

Comment: may be use array_chunk() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: @Lev you need to print two by two images instead all in a row ??

Answer (score 1):

`$this->db->limit(2);` to limit results to the first two images.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But what I need is to limit 2 image per page. Like image 1 and 2 on PAGE 1, image 3 and 4 on PAGE 2 and so on and so forth. And I guess that $this->db->limit(2); doesn't work on that way am I right?

Comment: I see no page/pagination code in your question hence my confusion. You should try and implement pagination using the CI pagination library.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is known as **Pagination** in web development world. You have not implemented any pagination logic. You have to use Pagination to achieve desired result.

Refer this link for reference [Pagination with CI](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/codeigniter-tutorials/pagination-using-php-codeigniter).

I hope this will give you fair idea.